# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.services.storage.model.RewriteResponse.getObjectSize()Ljava/math/BigInteger;

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I'm using `com.google.cloud.storage` to copy objects in storage

here is my code:

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.*;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.CopyRequest;


    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    String copyBlobName = "copy_blob_name";
    String bucketName = "my_unique_bucket";
    String blobName = "my_blob_name";
    CopyRequest request = CopyRequest.newBuilder()
            .setSource(BlobId.of(bucketName, blobName))
            .setTarget(BlobId.of(copyBlobName, copyBlobName))
            .build();
    storage.copy(request);
```

the copy succeeded
but I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.services.storage.model.RewriteResponse.getObjectSize()Ljava/math/BigInteger;
at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.DefaultStorageRpc.rewrite(DefaultStorageRpc.java:669)
at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.DefaultStorageRpc.openRewrite(DefaultStorageRpc.java:634)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$15.call(StorageImpl.java:438)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$15.call(StorageImpl.java:435)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:179)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:244)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.copy(StorageImpl.java:435)
```

in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.3-beta</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This almost certainly means that there is a versioning problem: you are running your code on a different version of Google Cloud Storage than what you are compiling it with. The method you are trying to compile exists in the version you are using for compiling, but not in the version you use for running. Make sure you compile with the same version of the library as what's on the runtime system.

Comment: There is a versioning conflict with your third party dependencies here. Since you are using Maven to build, take a look at your dependency tree. That way you can see conflicting versions and add explicit exclusions on transitive dependencies. I.e. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html.